# how to show a two methods data asynchronously using async and await in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, model-view-controller, async-await

i have two methods. i need to show two action methods data in asynchronously. i want the first method viewbag should be shown in view page after 3 seconds i need to show second viewbag data. actually i have multiple web request i have to use. i don't want to block the thread or view until all the web requests are performed.every method i want to call separate rest api and show the response in the view asynchrounously.

code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Task one =   Method1();
        Task two = Method1();

        return View();
    }

    public async Task Method1()
    {

        ViewBag.method1 = "method1";

    }

    public async Task method2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        ViewBag.method2 = "method2";

    }
}
```

view

```
@ViewBag.method1 <hr />
@ViewBag.method2
```

Comment: Send ajax request from client to the server. The delay part is not relevant to server and it's a client requirement (unless you are creating some push notifications).

Comment: i want to do server side . i need to show methods response one by one in the view.

Comment: It's web application and it means the client should send a request to get the response. So send a request to `/controller/action1` and return a view showing the result from `action1`. Than at client-side after 3 seconds, send an ajax request to `/controller/action2` and get the response and append it to some element in the page.

Comment: The web is request/response. You don't get to (from the server side) spontaneously send a second response some time later.

Comment: is there any solution with async and await task keywords or concepts

Comment: This problem doesn't have anything o do with async/await. See the example which I shared as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Send ajax request from client to the server. The delay part is not relevant to server and it's a client requirement (unless you are creating some push notifications).

It's web application and it means the client should send a request to get the response. So send a request to `/controller/index` and return a view showing the result from `action1` by `RenderAction`. Than at client-side after 3 seconds, send an ajax request to `/controller/action2` and get the response and show it in some element in the page:

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return Content("Action 1 result.");
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return Content("Action 2 result.");
    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
<div id="action1">
    @{Html.RenderAction("action1");}
</div>
<div id="action2">Wait for 3 seconds ...</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/home/action2',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: (data) => { $('#action2').html(data); },
                    error: () => { alert('Error'); }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
}
```